# How to properly provide appdata.xml file with autotools?

Tags: xml, autotools, gnome, appdata

What is the right way to carry a **appdata.xml** file with autotools?
The [documentation](http://people.freedesktop.org/~hughsient/appdata/) says that it should be installed at `/usr/share/appdata/%{id}.appdata.xml`. Is it the developer or the packager's responsibility?

What about translation? How to make the appdata.xml translatable? The documentation evokes appdata.xml.in but does not give a full example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the documentation provides a sample.

In `Makefile.am`, add

```
@INTLTOOL_XML_RULE@
appdatadir = $(datarootdir)/appdata
appdata_DATA = $(appdata_in_files:.xml.in=.xml)
appdata_in_files = YOURAPP.appdata.xml.in

CLEANFILES = \
    ...
    $(appdata_DATA) \
    ...
```

And provides a file `YOURAPP.appdata.xml.in` with translatable XML tags prefixed with an underscore, for instance `<_foobar>translatable text</_foobar>`